# implementation of unzip function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement the unzip function, I did the following code but I get error.

```
myUnzip [] =()
myUnzip ((a,b):xs) = a:fst (myUnzip xs)  b:snd (myUnzip xs)
```

I know that problem is in the right side of the second line but I do know how to improve it .
any hint please .

the error that I am getting is

```
ex1.hs:190:22:
Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `[a0]'
In the expression: a : fst (myUnzip xs) b : snd (myUnzip xs)
In an equation for `myUnzip':
    myUnzip ((a, b) : xs) = a : fst (myUnzip xs) b : snd (myUnzip xs)


ex1.hs:190:29:
Couldn't match expected type `(t0 -> a0, b0)' with actual type `()'
In the return type of a call of `myUnzip'
In the first argument of `fst', namely `(myUnzip xs)'
In the first argument of `(:)', namely `fst (myUnzip xs) b'

ex1.hs:190:49:
Couldn't match expected type `(a1, [a0])' with actual type `()'
In the return type of a call of `myUnzip'
In the first argument of `snd', namely `(myUnzip xs)'
In the second argument of `(:)', namely `snd (myUnzip xs)'
```

Comment: Can you share with us what error you're getting?

Comment: hi Pippin, I just realize that I wrongly used first instead of fst and second instead of snd so I fixed my mistake and put the error up

Comment: Actually, there's an error in your first line as well: `()` does not have the type `([a], [b])` but `([], [])` does.

Comment: Think about how `a:fst (myUnzip xs)` and `b:snd (myUnzip xs)`. Right now you just juxtaposed them, which, in Haskell, means function application. You need to create a pair instead.

Comment: I got it , so I am just going to put the right answer below

Comment: uz [] = ([],[])
uz ((x,y):xs) = (x:as, y:bs)
    where (as, bs) = uz xs -- uz [(2,5),(4,6),(5,7)] -> ([2,4,5],[5,6,7])

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do it inefficiently by traversing the list twice

```
myUnzip [] = ([], []) -- Defaults to a pair of empty lists, not null
myUnzip xs = (map fst xs, map snd xs)
```

But this isn't very ideal, since it's bound to be quite slow compared to only looping once.  To get around this, we have to do it recursively

```
myUnzip [] = ([], [])
myUnzip ((a, b):xs) = (a : ???, b : ???)
    where ??? = myUnzip xs
```

I'll let you fill in the blanks, but it should be straightforward from here, just look at the type signature of `myUnzip` and figure out what you can possible put in place of the question marks at `where ??? = myUnzip xs`

Comment: here is what I did after reading your guide but it is still complaining can you help me ? myUnzip' [] = ([],[])
myUnzip' ((a,b):xs) = (a:(fst rest), b:(snd rest))
    where rest = myUnzip' xs

Comment: I got it , so I am just going to put the right answer below , thanks bro

Comment: Are you sure the second version is faster than the first?

Comment: @augustss Nope, but it does do it in a single loop.

Comment: @bheklilr A single loop that allocates two cons cells and a pair in each iteration.  Versus two loops which allocate a cons cell in each iteration.  I don't know either, but it's not always looping that is the most expensive.

Comment: @augustss Interestingly, you are correct, the two loop method using maps is the fastest according to criterion.  I ran it to 1000 samples on several different implementations, including Prelude's, and on my computer the map implementation ran in about 75-80% of the time as the recursive, and about 55-75% of the time as `Prelude.unzip`.  The lower bounds were with `-N4` and the upper bounds were without threaded enabled at all.  This was for an input list of size 50000, so I don't know how well it scales, but for relatively large input it does seem to be faster to use maps.

Comment: @augustss, the biggest potential downside of the double map is that it can retain memory longer than necessary, since an ininspected output thunk will link to an otherwise-possibly-dead element. Also, note that you counted the pair in the single-pass solution, but not the (admittedly potential) `fst` or `snd` application thunk in the other.

Comment: uz [] = ([],[])
uz ((x,y):xs) = (x:as, y:bs)
    where (as, bs) = uz xs -- uz [(2,5),(4,6),(5,7)] -> ([2,4,5],[5,6,7])

Answer (score 5):

I thought it might be interesting to display two alternative solutions. In practice you wouldn't use these, but they might open your mind to some of the possibilities of Haskell.

First, there's the direct solution using a fold -

```
unzip' xs = foldr f x xs
  where
    f (a,b) (as,bs) = (a:as, b:bs)
    x               = ([],   [])
```

This uses a combinator called `foldr` to iterate through the list. Instead, you just define the combining function `f` which tells you how to combine a single pair `(a,b)` with a pair of lists `(as, bs)`, and you define the initial value `x`.

Secondly, remember that there is the nice-looking solution

```
unzip'' xs = (map fst xs, map snd xs)
```

which looks neat, but performs two iterations of the input list. It would be nice to be able to write something as straightforward as this, but which only iterates through the input list once.

We can *nearly* achieve this using the `Foldl` library. For an explanation of why it doesn't quite work, see the note at the end - perhaps someone with more knowledge/time can explain a fix.

First, import the library and define the identity fold. You may have to run `cabal install foldl` first in order to install the library.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Foldl

ident = Fold (\as a -> a:as) [] reverse
```

You can then define folds that extract the first and second components of a list of pairs,

```
fsts = map fst <$> ident
snds = map snd <$> ident
```

And finally you can combine these two folds into a single fold that unzips the list

```
unzip' = (,) <$> fsts <*> snds
```

The reason that this doesn't quite work is that although you only traverse the list once to extract the pairs, they will be extracted in reverse order. This is what necessitates the additional call to `reverse` in the definition of `ident`, which results in an extra traversal of the list, to put it in the right order. I'd be interested to learn of a way to fix that up (I expect it's not possible with the current `Foldl` library, but might be possible with an analogous `Foldr` library that gives up streaming in order to preserve the order of inputs).

---

Note that neither of these work with infinite lists. The solution using `Foldl` will never be able to handle infinite lists, because you can't observe the value of a left fold until the list has terminated.

However, the version using a right fold *should* work - but at the moment it isn't lazy enough. In the definition

```
unzip' xs = foldr f x xs
  where
    f (a,b) (as,bs) = (a:as, b:bs) -- problem is in this line!
    x               = ([],   [])
```

the pattern match requires that we open up the tuple in the second argument, which requires evaluating one more step of the fold, which requires opening up another tuple, which requires evaluating one more step of the fold, etc. However, if we use an irrefutable pattern match (which always succeeds, without having to examine the pattern) we get just the right amount of laziness -

```
unzip'' xs = foldr f x xs
  where
    f (a,b) ~(as,bs) = (a:as, b:bs)
    x                = ([],   [])
```

so we can now do

```
>> let xs = repeat (1,2)
>> take 10 . fst . unzip'  $ xs
^CInterrupted
<< take 10 . fst . unzip'' $ xs
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Comment: The "fold" package seems to include left folds, right folds and much more besides.  [See below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20347554/997606).

Comment: @TomEllis I should probably point out that neither of my solutions, nor your solution with `Data.Fold` work with infinite lists. I wonder if it's possible to define compositional folds that can handle infinite lists.

Comment: It *can* be done, because that's what Pipes is (partly) about :) The left fold won't work because it relies on reverse.  The right fold *should* work but the implementation of `(<*>)` is insufficiently lazy.  [See my bug report](https://github.com/ekmett/folds/issues/2).

Comment: Yes, you're right - and you can fix up the `foldr` example in my answer by using an irrefutable pattern match too.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me that this would be a sensible thing for the folds library to do in general, so I somewhat hedged my bets on the bug report.  I guess edwardk will know whether the lazy pattern match is sensible in general or not.

Answer (score 2):

Here's [Chris Taylor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20347138/997606) written using the (somewhat new) "folds" package:

```
import Data.Fold (R(R), run)
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))

ident :: R a [a]
ident = R id (:) []

fsts :: R (a, b) [a]
fsts = map fst <$> ident

snds :: R (a, b) [b]
snds = map snd <$> ident

unzip' :: R (a, b) ([a], [b])
unzip' = (,) <$> fsts <*> snds

test :: ([Int], [Int])
test = run [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)] unzip'

*Main> test
([1,3,5],[2,4,6])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I got working after above guidances

```
myUnzip' [] = ([],[])
myUnzip' ((a,b):xs) = (a:(fst rest), b:(snd rest))
    where rest = myUnzip' xs
```

Comment: good. you could even do `(a:as, b:bs) where (as,bs)=myUnzip' xs`

Answer (score 0):

```hs
myunzip :: [(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])
myunzip xs = (firstValues xs , secondValues xs)
          where
            firstValues :: [(a,b)] -> [a]
            firstValues [] = []
            firstValues (x : xs) = fst x : firstValues xs

            secondValues :: [(a,b)] -> [b]
            secondValues [] = []
            secondValues (x : xs) = snd x : secondValues xs
```