# Functionally solving questions: how to use Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I am trying to solve one of the problem in H99:
Split a list into two parts; the length of the first part is given.

Do not use any predefined predicates.

Example:

```
> (split '(a b c d e f g h i k) 3)
( (A B C) (D E F G H I K))
```

And I can quickly come with a solution:

```
split'::[a]->Int->Int->[a]->[[a]]
split' [] _ _ _     = []
split' (x:xs) y z w = if y == z then [w,xs] else split' xs y (z+1) (w++[x])

split::[a]->Int->[[a]]
split x y = split' x y 0 []
```

My question is that what I am doing is kind of just rewriting the loop version in a recursion format. Is this the right way you do things in Haskell? Isn't it just the same as imperative programming?

EDIT: Also, how do you generally avoid the extra function here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's convenient that you can often convert an imperative solution to Haskell, but you're right, you do usually want to find a more natural recursive statement. For this one in particular, reasoning in terms of base case and inductive case can be very helpful. So what's your base case? Why, when the split location is 0:

```
split x 0 = ([], x)
```

The inductive case can be built on that by prepending the first element of the list onto the result of splitting with n-1:

```
split (x:xs) n = (x:left, right)
  where (left, right) = split xs (n-1)
```

This may not perform wonderfully (it's probably not as bad as you'd think) but it illustrates my thought process when I first encounter a problem and want to approach it functionally.

**Edit**: Another solution relying more heavily on the Prelude might be:

```
split l n = (take n l, drop n l)
```

Comment: Oh that "Un-haskellish" remark was for the OP original solution, I like yours :) It's how I first wrote is as well, but I think tail recursion is important for these sort of functions

Comment: I agree that tail recursion is important, but I think beginners are here for elegance first, and should grasp the basics before worrying about performance.

Comment: I was curious what the Platform/GHC has, and it's the `(take n l, drop n l)` solution. Dunno exactly why, but it's worth mentioning that the Platform/GHC versions of `take` and `drop` have the list fusion optimization, so the point is that both elements of the tuple are "good producers" such that they can fuse into the same loop as their consumers. (Which is another reason why Haskell beginners should not be pushed into tail recursion—in Haskell, thanks to laziness and fusion optimizations, we often have "tail recursion bad, non-tail recursion good" situations...

Comment: @LuisCasillas If you're going to be fully strict in your results, tail recursion wins, if you're not, guarded recursion + optimizations wins.

Comment: @jozefg Yes, but when it comes to explaining things to newcomers, you often have to battle the misconceptions (often from previous exposure to strict functional languages like ML or Scheme) that tail recursion will necessarily use constant space and non-tail recursion will necessarily use linear space. As you and I know, neither of these statements is generally true in Haskell. But I too often see newcomers bend themselves backwards to write a tail-recursive version of something that is best written as a `foldr`—one of my favorite examples is `find`.

Comment: @jozefg and LuiCasillas I helped on a [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20340986/839246) recently that was to implement `unzip`, and using a solution somewhat similar to jozefg's below turned out to actually be slower than just doing `(map fst l, map snd l)` by a significant margin.  It may be that the recursive definition is slower in certain cases than just using `(take n l, drop n l)`.

Comment: @LuisCasillas Fair enough, PS I benchmarked `Data.List.splitAt` on my system out of curioisity, mine clocked in at 15 seconds and prelude at 20 seconds

Comment: @bheklilr Interesting, the opposite seems to hold in this case, where you strict in both the resulting lists?

Comment: Update: tried this benchmark on the above solution and crashed my machine.. whooops

Comment: @jozefg I bet being strict on both lists makes a big difference—possibly what's happening is that anything that looks like `fst . splitAt n` gets inlined/optimized to just `take n`, which can then fuse very well with producers and consumers.

Comment: Oh, I messed up, I misread the `Data.List` source code (actually, `GHC.List`).  It is using a tail-recursive version. My apologies.

Comment: @jozefg You might be correct, I may have had my strictness wrong.  I attempted a few extra variations of `unzip` with bang patterns and got one down to 70% of prelude's implementation, but it does not work on infinite lists.

Comment: @bheklilr Yeah, however tail recursion is applicable here because even a tail recursive solution terminates on an infinite list (it's recursing on the `Int` not the list)

Answer (score 3):

It's not the same as imperative programming really, each function call avoids any side effects, they're just simple expressions. But I have a suggestion for your code

```
split :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
split p xs = go p ([], xs)
  where go 0 (xs, ys) = (reverse xs, ys)
        go n (xs, y:ys) = go (n-1) (y : xs, ys)
```

So how we've declared that we're only returning two things `([a], [a])` instead of a list of things (which is a bit misleading) and that we've constrained our tail recursive call to be in local scope.

I'm also using pattern matching, which is a more idiomatic way to write recursive functions in Haskell, when `go` is called with a zero, then the first case is run. It's more pleasant generally to write recursive functions that go down rather than up since you can use pattern matching rather than if statements.

Finally this is more efficient since `++` is linear in the length of the first list, which means that the complexity of your function is quadratic rather than linear. This method is also tail recursive unlike Daniel's solution, which is important for handling any large lists.

TLDR: Both versions are functional style, avoiding mutation, using recursion instead of loops. But the version I've presented is a little more Haskell-ish and slightly faster.

#### A word on tail recursion

This solution uses tail recursion **which isn't always essential in Haskell** but in this case is helpful when you use the resulting lists, but at other times is actually a bad thing. For example, `map` isn't tail recursive, but if it was you couldn't use it over infinite lists!

In this case, we can use tail recursion, since an integer is always finite. But, if we only use the first element of the list, Daniel's solution is **much** faster, since it produces the list lazily. On the other hand, if we use the whole list, my solution is much faster.

Comment: tail recursion is only good in Haskell when it builds the value that is needed in full (like numbers). Not so with lists. your version is unnecessarily strict. guarded recursion is always preferable, is my understanding. and seeing `reverse` is just terrible, :) w.r.t. laziness etc.

Comment: @WillNess Yeah, this solution isn't lazy in the first list, but I addressed this in the "A word on tail recursion" part.

Comment: yes, I see it now. that `reverse` just jumped at me.  :) I think rule of thumb can safely be set, tail recursion is almost always the wrong thing  to do in Haskell, unless it's a right thing to do. In the end what matters is run time behaviour - time *and* space. Guarded rec will more likely run in constant space.

Answer (score -1):

```
split'::[a]->Int->([a],[a])

split' [] _ = ([],[])
split' xs 0 = ([],xs)
split' (x:xs) n = (x:(fst splitResult),snd splitResult) 
                  where splitResult = split' xs (n-1)
```

*It seems you have already shown an example of a better solution.*

I would recommend you read [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). Then you come to the conclusion that the extra function is normal. There's also widely used approach to hide functions in the local area. The book may seem boring to you but in the early chapters she will get used to the functional approach in solving problems.

There are tasks in which the recursive approach is more necessary. But for example if you use tail recursion (which is so often praised without cause) then you will notice that this is just the usual iteration. Often with "extra-function" which hide iteration variable (oh.. word variable is not very appropriate, likely argument).

Comment: I think "the extra function is normal" is easy enough to grasp it needn't necessitate a year-long study of a long and dense computer science tome.

Comment: @DanielLyons But this book is for first-year students. And there is beginner question (it seemed).

Comment: I love SICP and think everyone should read it, but to doing it to learn that idiomatic Scheme uses block structure to make hidden local functions isn't really relevant to the task at hand. Also, what makes a good functional program in a lazy vs strict language is a big difference

Comment: @DanielLyons SICP is fun and good and is really accessible. You don't really need to know Scheme to read it, just go ahead and skim through the book. When you see `(define (sqrt a b) ...)` it is indeed what you think it is. :)

Comment: @WillNess All that's accomplished by mentioning SICP here is meaningless flashing of gang signs. Neither the question nor the answer relate to it. The dictionary defines every word, but that doesn't make it pertain to every question and every answer. Stick to the point.

Comment: @DanielLyons I understand your point of view. Myself have often seen fanatical tips read it and read the book recently. I think it's a good practice to criticize the repeated advice.

Comment: @DanielLyons you said it's "dense computer science tome". I just wanted to say that it's really not, IMHO. the answer suggested it, you came against, I wanted to support the position given in this answer. Having a good-natured and fun discussion, you know. My wording might have been a bit off.